# Which adjective describes the "either ... or ..." relationship?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective that describes the "either ... or ..." relationship between two concepts?

Here by "either ... or ...", I mean mutual exclusiveness and exhaustiveness. Or logically speaking, the "either ... or ..." relationship can be thought of as the relationship between a proposition and its negation.

Let me use two examples to clarify what I need.

1. Suppose I'm an elementary school student and I just learned about odd and even numbers. I'm don't know if a integer can be both odd and even (multual exclusive), and I don't know if every integer must be odd or even (exhaustiveness). So I go to my teacher and ask "is a integer either odd or even?". Can I rephrase my question like "are odd and even numbers ____?"?
2. Suppose instead I'm a college student now and I just learned about open and closed sets. Misled by the their names, I thought that a set must be open if it's not closed and vice versa, until my professor told me that "open sets and closed sets are not ____".

I want an adjective that fits into those blanks above.

---

After reading all the answers and comments, as well as related questions, I think the "either ... or ..." phrase might be the simplest and most suitable way, as least for everyday usage. Just say "an X is either A or B" instead of "A and B are ____"

Comment: It is a binary situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the word for always YES (100%) or always NO (0%), never in-between](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316344/what-is-the-word-for-always-yes-100-or-always-no-0-never-in-between) Or [What is a term to refer to two ideas in exact opposition eg good-bad?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329278/what-is-a-term-to-refer-to-two-ideas-in-exact-opposition-e-g-good-bad-posit/329424#329424)?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I think that question emphasizes on a situation,  in which you may need to make a decision. I don't think the odd and even numbers example above fits into that question well.

Comment: Could they be considered opposites?

Comment: @youzer: I don't know if "opposite" completely captures that. Opposite should describe the mutual exclusiveness, but how about the exhaustiveness, i.e. no third possibility?

Comment: You could work with Edwin Ashworth's "binary situation", which describes what you are asking for well.  You might speak of a 'binary choice'.  In logical terms what you would have is an 'exclusive disjunction':  Either A or B (but not both) must be true.

Comment: `XOR` has truth table FTTF, whereas `OR` has TTTF. They're two different logical functors, but the English disjunction _or_ can refer to both, in different contexts. I.e, this is not a linguistic difference, certainly not an English one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematical literature, "complete" is the usual term, e.g.

> *...completeness implies that there are not any “gaps” (in Dedekind's terminology) or “missing points” in the real number line...*
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers
>
> *The Completeness of the Integers, John McCuan, February 25, 2020* [https://people.math.gatech.edu/~mccuan/courses/4317/integers2.pdf](https://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Emccuan/courses/4317/integers2.pdf)

Picking up on the comment by @271828, I would say that "exhaustive" is equally correct in general speech. It doesn't even depend on there being merely two alternatives.

E.g. *The digits 0-9 are **exhaustive** when it comes to expressing the numbers from zero to one hundred.*

In other words they exhaust the possibilities. In less formal terms, you could say "all encompassing", however your example is mathematical and so formal by definition.

EDIT

Incidentally, the terms *necessary* and *sufficient* are relevant here. For example Even and Odd numbers are *sufficient* to encompass the integers but they aren't *necessary*, i.e. you can describe integers in a different way.

Comment: I used a mathematical example, but I don't want the mathematical terminology for specific. (I added another mathematical example to the question to futuer clarify, I don't know why all I came up with were math terms [face with tears of joy]).After viewing all the answers and comments, I think maybe the "either ... or ..." phrase is the simplest way for everyday usage. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the word *dichotomous*?

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dichotomous) defines *dichotomous* as

> Exhibiting or characterized by dichotomy,

and [dichotomy](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dichotomous) as

> A division or contrast between two things that are or are represented as being opposed or entirely different.

Comment: That sounds a bit intimidating in everyday use. What I need is a adj that describes both mutual exclusiveness and exhaustiveness. Suppose I'm a elementary school student and I just learned about odd and even numbers but I'm not sure if they form all the integers, so I ask my teacher "is a integer either even or odd?". Can I rephrase my question as "are even and odd numbers ____?"